# MySQL Stored Procedure: Boolean Logic in IF THEN

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm looking for the proper syntax (if this is possible in MySQL stored procedures) for using logical operators in an IF THEN statement.  Here's something along the lines of what I would like to do, but I'm not certain if I should type "OR" or "||" in the IF ... THEN clause:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `MyStoredProc` (_id INT)
BEGIN

  DECLARE testVal1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE testVal2 INT DEFAULT 0;

  SELECT value1, value2 INTO testVal1, testVal2 
    FROM ValueTable 
   WHERE id = _id;

 IF testVal1 > 0 OR testVal2 > 0 THEN

   UPDATE ValueTable 
      SET value1 = (value1+1) 
    WHERE id=_id;

 END IF;

END$$
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried your procedure to be sure it works, and it does. Also, you should consider specifying the length of your variable's types, eg. INT(10).

Both the **`OR`** and **`||`** operators are correct (as stated in the [Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or)).

Comment: what kind of error message (code) do you get? the `OR` and `||` operators are both correct.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with stored procedures, but "or" works for triggers. Here's a working snippet out of some current production code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_inventory` AFTER INSERT ON `order_updates` FOR EACH ROW 
begin
   if new.type = 'received' or new.type = 'used' or new.type = 'returned' then 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the code to deal with the possibility of `NULL` values (which could be the hidden reason for the error you are experiencing).

For example:

```
IF (testVal1 IS NOT NULL AND testVal1 > 0) OR (testVal2 IS NOT NULL AND testVal2 > 0) THEN

   UPDATE ValueTable 
      SET value1 = (value1+1) 
    WHERE id=_id;

 END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although || and OR should cause the same result
in the case that you supplied, OR is better because it is
consistent while || is affected by sql_mode. Here's an absurd
example where a result of OR is false and a result of || is true.
(I use a client that doesn't need delimiter statements, but if you have the regular mysql client then you will know where to add them.)

```
set @or1='false';
set @or2='false';
set sql_mode='db2';
drop procedure p;
create procedure p()
begin
  declare a char default 'a';
  if a > 0 || a = 0 then set @or1 = 'true'; end if;
  if a > 0 or a = 0 then set @or2 = 'true'; end if;
end;
call p();
select @or1,@or2;
```